# How to Pin Data in Toad for Oracle

Tags: toad

How to Pin a result set so it is not overwritten by a subsequent query in TOAD for Oracle (Expert).
   I have checked out all options, but unable to pin data.

```
        Thanks
```

Comment: This is not possible. You can keep one tab open for your pinned data and execute in another tab your other queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple Schema Browser windows (Database | Schema browser) in the particular session (connection). And multiple Editor windows (Database | Editor) too. In each Editor window you can open multiple SQL tabs.
(Toad for Oracle Xpert 9.7.2.5)